# Entity framework context is adding an invalid column in select query

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

Here is my classes properties:

```
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Creation { get; set; }
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set;         
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Properties { get; set; }
    public bool OnFrontPage { get; set; }
    public int StockCount { get; set; }
    public decimal MarketPrice { get; set; }
    public int CurrencyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Currency Currency { get; set; }
    public int TaxRate { get; set; }
    public bool IsNewProduct { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
    public string MetaKeyWord { get; set; }
    public int UnitId { get; set; }
    public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }
    public int PointValue { get; set; }
    public string RelatedProductIds { get; set; }
    public int MaxSaleCount { get; set; }
    public int ProductGroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductGroup ProductGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ProductType> ProductTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Promotion> Promotions { get; set; }
    public int SaleCount { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ProductChance> ProductChances { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
```

Here is sql query which created by context. Context adding [Category_CategoryId] column however I don't have anything about category in my class or in my databe table

```
  SELECT 
[Extent1].[ProductId] AS [ProductId], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Creation] AS [Creation], 
[Extent1].[BrandId] AS [BrandId], 
[Extent1].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
[Extent1].[Price] AS [Price], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[Properties] AS [Properties], 
[Extent1].[OnFrontPage] AS [OnFrontPage], 
[Extent1].[StockCount] AS [StockCount], 
[Extent1].[MarketPrice] AS [MarketPrice], 
[Extent1].[CurrencyId] AS [CurrencyId], 
[Extent1].[TaxRate] AS [TaxRate], 
[Extent1].[IsNewProduct] AS [IsNewProduct], 
[Extent1].[IsActive] AS [IsActive], 
[Extent1].[MetaDescription] AS [MetaDescription], 
[Extent1].[MetaKeyWord] AS [MetaKeyWord], 
[Extent1].[UnitId] AS [UnitId], 
[Extent1].[PointValue] AS [PointValue], 
[Extent1].[RelatedProductIds] AS [RelatedProductIds], 
[Extent1].[MaxSaleCount] AS [MaxSaleCount], 
[Extent1].[ProductGroupId] AS [ProductGroupId], 
[Extent1].[SaleCount] AS [SaleCount], 
[Extent1].[ProductCode] AS [ProductCode], 
[Extent1].[Category_CategoryId] AS [Category_CategoryId]
FROM [dbo].[Product] AS [Extent1]}
```

Category:

```
public int CategoryId { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; }
public string LinkText { get; set; }
public int? ParentId { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
public bool IsActive { get; set; }
public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }
public DateTime Creation { get; set; }
public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
public bool IsParentCategory { get; set; }
```

Comment: Could you show the Category class ?

Comment: Are you using code-first? If so then it may be with how you've set up the relation ship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you probably setted the relationship as a one to many (or it's done by EF when you have an IList of another entity, without anything on the other part, I must admit I don't know that).

Anyway, that's not because you don't wanna see a Navigation proprety "Category" in your product class that the Database don't need a FK to keep the relation between these two entities.

The needs of a database are not the same as it's object's counterpart.

Other example : if you create a many to many relation ship

```
public class A {
public virtual IList<B> Bs {get;set;}
}

public class B {
 public virtual IList<A> As {get;set;}
}
```

EF will create a table A, a table B, and a table AB. But in the object world, the AB table is not present as an Entity (not needed).